# Sklearn's SimpleImputer doesn't work in a pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has some NaN values in a particular column:

```
1291   NaN
1841   NaN
2049   NaN
Name: some column, dtype: float64
```

And I have made the following pipeline in order to deal with it:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean = True)
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')
logistic = LogisticRegression()

pipe = Pipeline([('imputer', imputer),
                 ('scaler', scaler), 
                 ('logistic', logistic)])
```

Now when I pass this pipeline to a `RandomizedSearchCV`, I get the following error:

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

It's actually quite a bit longer than that -- I can post the entire error in an edit if neccesary. Anyway, I am quite sure that this column is the only column that contains NaNs. Moreover, if I switch from `SimpleImputer` to the (now deprecated) `Imputer` in the pipeline, the pipeline works just fine in my `RandomizedSearchCV`. I checked the documentation, but it seems that `SimpleImputer` is supposed to behave in (nearly) the exact same way as `Imputer`. What is the difference in behavior? How do use an imputer in my pipeline without using the deprecated `Imputer`?

Comment: Do you get same error if you run `SimpleImputer` independently (not from a pipeline)?

Comment: Finding the same error when I pass - `SimpleImputer( 
                                  strategy='constant', 
                                  fill_value=0)`

Comment: Comment by @FrédérandOuweric: Did you check that the target variable doesn't contain NaN values? The Imputer only handles missing values in the input features.

Comment: I had the same issue. Turned out I explicitly had to specify missing_values=None . I would expect this to be the default behaviour, actually.

Comment: This issues seems to be solved here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21112

Answer (score 1):

SimpleImputer in make_pipeline

```
preprocess_pipeline = make_pipeline(   
    FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
        ('Handle numeric columns', make_pipeline(
            ColumnSelector(columns=['Amount']),
            SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0),
            StandardScaler()
        )),
        ('Handle categorical data', make_pipeline(
            ColumnSelector(columns=['Type', 'Name', 'Changes']),
            SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', missing_values=' ', fill_value='missing_value'),
            OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
        ))
    ])
)
```

SimpleImputer in Pipeline

```
('features', FeatureUnion ([
     ('Cat Columns', Pipeline([
          ('Category Extractor', TypeSelector(np.number)),
                 ('Impute Zero', SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value=0))
                                    ])),
('Numerics', Pipeline([
      ('Numeric Extractor', TypeSelector("category")),
          ('Impute Missing', SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value='missing'))
          ]))        
     ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but this addressed it:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median', fill_value = 0)
```